# How to analyze the roots of two variable $p$-adic power series $f(x,y)$ in the maximal ideal $m$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, weierstrass-preparation

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$-adic field, $O_K$ be the ring of integer and $m$ be the maximal ideal.

Consider the single variable  $p$-adic power series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n \in O_K[[x]]$ of Weierstrass degree $d$ (i.e., not all $a_n$ belongs to $m$ and $a_d$ is first unit coefficient appears in the series). Then there exists a unit power series $u(x) \in O_K[[x]]$ and a polynomial $F(x) \in O_K[x]$ of the form $F(x)=x^d+b_{s-1}x^{d-1}+\cdots+b_1x+b_0$ with $b_i \in m$ such that $f=uF$. In this case $f$ has total $d$ roots in $m$.

Now consider a two variable $p$-adic power series $f(x,y) \in \sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty} a_{mn}x^my^n \in O_K[[x,y]]$ such that Weierstrass degree of $f$ is $d$ in the variable $x$. Then there exists a polynomial $P=x^d+b_{d-1}(y)x^{d-1}+b_1(y)x+b_0(y)$ in $O_K[[y]][x]$ of degree $d$, where the coefficients $b_i(y)$ are power series in $O_K[[y]]$. But, more precisely, I think $b_i(y) \in M$, where $M=\left\langle y \right\rangle \supset m$ is the maximal ideal of $O_K[[y]]$.

How to analyze the roots of $f(x,y)$ in the maximal ideal $m$ ?

I think there are $d$ values $a_i \in m, \ i=1,2,3, \cdots, d$ such that $f(a_i,y)=0$.

I hope there exists total $d$ roots of $f(x,y)$ in the maximal ideal $m$ or  $(x,y) \in m \times m$.

If so, what about simplicity of the roots ?

Any hints/help will be appreciated .

Comment: It seems that instead of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n$ with not all $a_n$ belonging to $m$, you want $\sum_{n = d}^\infty a_n x^n$ with $a_d$ not belonging to $m$.

Comment: @LSpice, yes, you are right. Actually, saying $\text{wideg(f)}=d$ means $a_dx^d$ is lowest monomial such that $a_d \not\in m$.